# Using PHP with Google serial notification (IPN)

Tags: php, notifications, checkout

I'm trying to figure out how to get this working with PHP. I have a working IPN for paypal that is less than 20 lines of code to get the data I need. I have tried reading the Google docs but they are either way too specific or way too general. There is some sample code, which is about 1300 lines in 5 files and I can't make sense of it. I just need a handful of vars back from a completed transaction, nothing more. Is it possible to do this with a few lines of code (and I mean without 1300 lines worth of "include" files) or is Google Checkout's process really that bulky?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've gotten it to work, and here's the skeleton of my code that can be used to handle HTTP notifications/responses. This was obviously derived from tntu's example above. (Thanks!)

```
//incoming data is in the var $_POST['serial-number']
//"send" the response to acknowledge the serial number that google talks about all over but never explains how
echo "_type=notification-acknowledgment&serial-number=".$_POST['serial-number'];

//now we need to call google's server and ask for this transaction's data:
//you'll need to change your merchant id in the $url and $mid vars, and your merchant key in the $mky var
$url = "https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/reportsForm/Merchant/1234567890?_type=notification-history-request&serial-number=" . $_REQUEST['serial-number'];
$mid = "1234567890"; 
$mky = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
$aut = base64_encode($mid . ":" . $mky);

$arr = parse_url($url);
$ssl = "";
if($arr['scheme'] == "https") $ssl = "ssl://";

$post  = "POST " . $arr['path'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$post .= "Host: " . $arr['host'] . "\r\n";
$post .= "Authorization: Basic " . $aut . "\r\n";
$post .= "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$post .= "Accept: application/xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$post .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($arr['query']) . "\r\n";
$post .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
$post .= "\r\n";
$post .= $arr['query'];

//now we actually make the request by opening a socket and calling Google's server
$f = fsockopen($ssl . $arr['host'], 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if(!$f){
    //something failed in the opening of the socket, we didn't contact google at all, you can do whatever you want here such as emailing yourself about it and what you were trying to send, etc
    @mail("troubleshooting@yourdomain.com","Google IPN - HTTP ERROR ",$errstr . " (" . $errno . ")\n\n\n".$arr['query']);
}else{
    //the socket was opened, send the request for the order data: 
    fputs($f, $post); // you're sending
    while(!feof($f)) { $response .= @fgets($f, 128); } //google replies and you store it in $response
    fclose($f); //close the socket, we're done talking to google's server

    $spl=strpos($response,"_type="); //parse the type because parse_str won't catch it
    if ($spl!==false){
        $spl2=strpos($response,"&",$spl);
        $ordertype=substr($response,($spl+6),($spl2-$spl)-6);
    }//$ordertype will tell you which type of notification is being sent, new-order-notification, risk-information-notification, etc
    $subresponse=substr($response,$spl2+1); //put the rest of it into an array for easy access
    parse_str($subresponse,$order);//you can now access google's response in $order[] vars
    //IMPORTANT: dots in Google's field names are replaced by underscore, for example:
    // $order['google-order-number'] and $order['buyer-billing-address_address1'] NOT $order['buyer-billing-address.address1']
    //order field names are shown here: 
    //https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Notification_API#order_summary

     //this is the point where you will want to use the data contained in $order[] to create a new record in your database or whatever.
    //NOTE: be sure to store and check for duplicates using the google-order-number because you will get multiple notifications from google regarding the same order

    if (strtoupper($order['order-summary_financial-order-state']) == "CHARGEABLE"){
        //CHARGEABLE is what indicates it is safe to create a login for the user (if you are delivering digital goods) 
        // insert into db, and/or email user with key or download url
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for answering your own question with a solution based on mine without even a +1.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I tried but it won't let me until I have 15 reputation points!

Comment: @tntu would it work better to edit your answer by replacing it with the code I posted and then delete this answer? (I want to at least include the echo, the comments, and the parsing to make it easier for the next person who tries to use it.) I don't care about points, I just don't want anyone else to have to deal with what I did just to get IPN working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of code I started. Not yet finished.
It works perfectly. 
All you need to do is take the data Google sends back and this code writes to a file and use it to insert into your sales table send notification of payment received to customer and so on.
The trick is that when Google sends you a post you must call back with and Authorization header or it will not take it in consideration.

```
function post2google($url, $timeout = 30, $port = 80, $buffer = 128) {
  $mid = "123456789";
  $mky = "qwertyuiop";
  $aut = base64_encode($mid . ":" . $mky);

  $arr = parse_url($url);

  $ssl = "";
  if($arr['scheme'] == "https") $ssl = "ssl://";

  $post  = "POST " . $arr['path'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $post .= "Host: " . $arr['host'] . "\r\n";

  $post .= "Authorization: Basic " . $aut . "\r\n";
  $post .= "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $post .= "Accept: application/xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

  $post .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($arr['query']) . "\r\n";
  $post .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
  $post .= "\r\n";
  $post .= $arr['query'];

  $f = fsockopen($ssl . $arr['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);

  if(!$f)
    return $errstr . " (" . $errno . ")";

  else{
    fputs($f, $post);
    while(!feof($f)) { $echo .= @fgets($f, $buffer); }
    fclose($f);

    return $echo;
  }
}
$re =  post2google("https://checkout.google.com/api/checkout/v2/reportsForm/Merchant/123456789?_type=notification-history-request&serial-number=" . $_REQUEST['serial-number'], 3, 443);

$re = str_replace("&", "\n", $re) . "\n\n--\n\n";

file_put_contents("gpn.txt", $re, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and post my results here, if I can ever get a sandbox account set up. It keeps signing me up for what appears to be a regular account.

Comment: Update: I still haven't gotten into the sandbox but did get an order for a different product which has been trying to send notifications, so I set up my IPN handler to use the above code and email me with what's happening.

Comment: If your authentication data is ok it will respond appropriately back to Google when they send the notification and that will be it. From that point on you need to look in the data Google sent if transaction is final and successful and insert it in your db so the user can download his product if it's digital or track if it's physical. You can also send the buyer an email. Note: Google will send more then one notification. One when order made and one when buyer has been successfully charged. At that stage you need to release the product.

Comment: Yeah, but one major problem I've had is with "look in the data Google sent" because nowhere have I found anything stating where/how I access that data. Do I look in the POST vars, in the REQUEST vars, a letter from Santa Claus, etc. Everyone assumes this is just common knowledge and says exactly the same, "process the data from Google." The other issue, because my weakness in PHP is dealing with cross-server communication, is how to construct the response Google wants, and how to "send" it. The above example seems to be geared to do those and is almost the same as my paypal IPN handler.

Comment: I added some lines to have the handler email me what it's doing. Google tried notifying it again and this time I got emails showing the data. (I believe it's in the URL? but anyway I can access it from the $echo var if nothing else.) I do have my merchant ID and key in there, but Google still said the response was invalid. So now I have enough to put the order in my DB and notify the buyer by email. But the other oddity is that it gave me "financial-order-state=REVIEWING" when I already marked it as charged and shipped in my checkout account.

Comment: Also in case it's relevant, I have for my checkout settings: "Callback contents: Notification Serial Number" and "API version 2.5" and "My company will only post digitally signed carts" is unchecked.

Comment: It's ECHO! It's friggin ECHO! I acknowledged their serial number like this:
`echo "_type=notification-acknowledgment&serial-number=".$_POST['serial-number'];`
and suddenly all the orders processed. 10,000 pages of documentation and not a single mention of that!